# Is it possible to check for a given python file whether it's pyc file is valid and up to date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bytecode, precompile, pyc

For a project which gets deployed to a RO filesystem I want to also deploy pre-compiled `.pyc` files for all of the Python source.

Thanks to the `compileall` module this already works, but due to whatever reasons caused by a complex build machinery, those `.pyc` files *can* become invalid accidentally (because of unwanted file modifications, source relocation, etc)

So what I'd like to do is to check if there's an already existing `pyc` file for each with would have been created, if it's being found and if it's valid (i.e. correct source path embedded, correct bytecode, etc).

Is there an integrated way to check "precompilation validity" (like `python3 -m compileall --check`)? Or what would be a pragmatic way to do this by hand? (e.g. by inspecting some trace or whatever).

The most reliable way I can imagine would be to compare a readily deployed tree to a copy where I deleted and re-created all files using `compileall`..

Comment: to perform this check it is necessary to understand what would cause a break. If moving directories causes a break, then this would need to be checked for.

Comment: However,  the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How long does it actually take to rebuild *all* the pyc files? I'm not sure you are actually saving yourself any work by trying to detect valid pyc files; you're just trading one kind of work for another.

Comment: (For comparison, it took my 9-year-old machine under 10 seconds to compile all the files under `cpython/Lib`, which amounts to ~1750 files, most of which were test suites.)

Comment: I'm not trying to save time but want to check a generated package before deployment. Running `compileall` at some time in your build process doesn't have the desired effect if there is some `rsync` later in your pipline invalidating all your `pyc` files. Later they can't be built because the package will be read only after installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at bytecode metadata using that disassembler called `pydisasm` that comes with  [`xdis`](https://pypi.org/project/xdis/) using option `--format` (or `-F`) option with `header`:

```
$ pydisasm --format header __pycache__/five.cpython-38.pyc 
# Python bytecode 3.8.0 (3413)
# Disassembled from Python 3.8.18 (default, Sep  4 2023, 13:19:52) 
# [GCC 12.3.0]
# Timestamp in code: 1708217267 (2024-02-17 19:47:47)
# Source code size mod 2**32: 148 bytes
# Embedded file name: five.py
```

If you want to get the information from Python, the internal routine that handles the header is called `show_module_header()`.

Be warned though that the last release of `xdis` on PyPI is over a year old, so use [code from github](https://github.com/rocky/python-xdis). In fact, I just fixed a bug for this option that prevented more header information from showing.

I will be [talking](https://www.blackhat.com/asia-24/briefings/schedule/index.html#how-to-get-the-most-out-of-the-python-decompilers-uncompyle-and-decompyle---how-to-write-and-read-a-bytecode-decompiler-37789) at [BlackHat Asia](https://www.blackhat.com/asia-24/) mid April 2024, so I plan to have a new xdis release sometime a little before that.